# tar --use-compress-program is broken on OSX

Tags: macos, tar

I installed pigz via homebrew on my Macbook Air (OS X 10.10.5) to get better performance for compress/decompress.

To compress, I use `tar --use-compress-program=pigz -cf test.tgz test` and it's ok.

But the command to uncompress, `tar --use-compress-program=pigz -xf test.tgz` output error:

`tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

Or sometimes it output:

`tar: Unrecognized archive format
pigz: abort: write error on <stdout> (Broken pipe)
tar: Child process exited with status 32
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

I read the [manual of tar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html), and have no clue why it doesn't work.

I noticed that even `tar --use-compress-program=gzip -xf test.tgz` generate the same error. So is this a bug of OSX's tar implementation?

Note: I know pipe style `pigz -d test.tgz | tar -xf` works and in this case I could also just use `tar -xf test.tgz` which call built-in gzip. But I just want to confirm whether it is a bug.

Comment: Similarly, sending options to the compression program fails, as in `--use-compress-program 'gzip -9'`. In this case the command silently fails, even in verbose mode, and produces a 0 byte file, which is just lovely. I mean broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program works as designed: there is no provision in its command-line to pass along the *options* needed to use `gzip` for decompressing.  Instead of "gzip" for decompressing, you should use the wrapped `gzcat`, e.g.,

```
tar --use-compress-program gzip -cf foo.compressed foo
tar --use-compress-program gzcat -tf foo.compressed
```

A quick check shows that this does not work:

```
tar --use-compress-program 'gzip -d' -tf foo.compress
```

although that could change some time (it is doable, but not done).

According to pigz's [manual page](http://zlib.net/pigz/pigz.pdf), it has `unpigz`, which is what you can use for *that* program.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue between BSD tar and GNU tar.

I fixed this by installing `gnu-tar` from homebrew and placing that on the path.

See this similar question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/318809/linux-os-x-tar-incompatibility-tarballs-created-on-os-x-give-errors-when-unt

Answer (score -1):

on linux I renamed gzip to gzip.sav and made a soft link to pigz so tar, dolphin, yum, and any other program that calls gzip actually calls pigz